# How to convert Volley StringRequest response into JSONArray?

Tags: java, android, json

I have create a StringRequest its bring me a string which is converted of an array.
I have added the function where the exception occur. I have no idea why its happening.

```
 public void getRegisterList() {
        progresLoader.present(DirecrBookingListActivity.this);
        Calendar current_date = Calendar.getInstance();
        from_date = current_date.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault())+" "+current_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+","+current_date.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        String url = Env.API_URL+"api/CustomerSMRIIndia/GetMobileBookingCountDashboard";
        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.d("Response", String.valueOf(response));
                        progresLoader.dismiss();
                        try {
                            JSONArray registerList = new JSONArray(response);
                            adapter=new DirectBookingListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), DirecrBookingListActivity.this, registerList);
                            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
                progresLoader.dismiss();
                requestErrorAlert(error);
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams()
            {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("FromDate", "2020-05-01");
                params.put("ToDate", "2020-05-01");
                params.put("Country_Id", String.valueOf(24));
                params.put("Outlet_Id", String.valueOf(413));
                params.put("UserID", String.valueOf(529));
                params.put("ContactedCRE_id", String.valueOf(storage.getDefaultsInt("CRE_id", getApplicationContext())));
                params.put("BrandType", "All");
                Log.d("Request Data", String.valueOf(params));
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(postRequest);
    }
```

This is response:

```
D/Response: "[{\"TotalBookingCount\":11,\"CREName\":\"Abhishek 
  Setia\",\"ServiceDoneCount\":0},{\"TotalBookingCount\":12,\"CREName\":\"Test 
  -01\",\"ServiceDoneCount\":0},{\"TotalBookingCount\":17,\"CREName\":\"Test 
  02\",\"ServiceDoneCount\":0},{\"TotalBookingCount\":11,\"CREName\":\"Test 
  03\",\"ServiceDoneCount\":0}]"
```

This is the ERROR:

```
 W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value [{"TotalBookingCount":11,"CREName":"Abhishek 
 Setia","ServiceDoneCount":0},{"TotalBookingCount":12,"CREName":"Test 
 -01","ServiceDoneCount":0},{"TotalBookingCount":17,"CREName":"Test 02","ServiceDoneCount":0}, 
 {"TotalBookingCount":11,"CREName":"Test 03","ServiceDoneCount":0}] of type java.lang.String 
 cannot be converted to JSONArray
2020-05-23 01:23:36.251 22336-22336/in.codepoetry.callrecordapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
2020-05-23 01:23:36.251 22336-22336/in.codepoetry.callrecordapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
2020-05-23 01:23:36.251 22336-22336/in.codepoetry.callrecordapp W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
```

PLEASE HELP ME TO SORT OUT THIS ISSUE

Comment: The elements of the JSON array don't have keys.

Comment: I have run your same code("new JSONArray(response)") with the same provided response and I didn't get any exception. This line "new JSONArray(response)" is returning JSON array. Provide some more details to get the exact issue.

Comment: @SujeetKumarGupta Still same exception

Comment: @Manabroy72 Provide a complete code of the function that contains the above piece of code.

Comment: @SujeetKumarGupta I have added the function where I got the exception